# OSX codesign for a specific macho binary

Tags: macos, codesign

I have a simple C code that i can gcc on my OS X. (I'm using El Capitan beta.) I know there are many guides for signing apps in Xcode. But I just want to codesign for this specific macho binary.

Is there any way to do it? Also, do i have to have an apple developer account to codesign this program? I'm not planning to release the binary to anyone. I'm just studying OSX stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use "codesign -s NAMEOFCERTIFICATEWITHINKEYCHAIN nameOfExecutable". To verify use "codesign --display --verbose=4 nameOfExecutable". But it is useless if you don't package it into bundle with bundle identifier,entitlements and valid signing certificate. Anyone can run your unsigned executable

Comment: Sorry, how can I have my own certificate keychain?

Comment: Open Keychain, click top menu (Keychain access), click certificate assistant and there create certificate. But this is different question. As I said you don't need it for console apps. If you do Cococa apps or you create frameworks, xpc connections then pay the membership  and you get certificate that apple is wiling to accept (certificate authority)